# select text of element using xpath with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

I have a structure like this :

```
<div class="content">
    <h3 class="faq">Joocey</h3>
        Locked Bag 4005
        <br> 
        6/78 William Street
        <br>
        Sydney NSW 2000
        <br> Customer Care: <a href="tel:1300886534">1300886534</a><br>
        or<br> help@joocey.com.au<br> <br>
        <div class="greenbar">
            <a href="/Stores">See All Stores <i class="icon-chevron-right icon-white pull-right">    </i</a>
        </div>
                    <!--greenbar-->

                    <!--main_footer-->
</div>
```

How to select each text line in `div[@class="content"]` ?

For example, I want to select :
"Joocey", "Locked Bag 4005", "6/78 William Street", "SydneyNSW 2000", "Customer Care:", "1300886534".

I have tried  `"//div[@class='content'][text()[2]]"` to select "Locked Bag 4005" but it always select all text. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

When you are selecting text by one of the DOM selectors, there is no concept of "line".

You are going to have to grab all of the text in `div[@class="content"]`, and then manipulate that as a string. Break it up on the new-line characters, and then access the resulting array.